# Replace the string which has a pattern like using sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, replace, sed

How to use like (.*) operation in sed to search a pattern (eg: STRING.*) and append "*" to the end of the string that matches.

Below is the example:

```
cat file1.txt 
MAC BOOK
MODERN MACHINE
MECHANICS
MOUNT
DISK
DATA INFORMATICS
```

```
cat file2.txt 
MAC
DATA
```

```
for line in $(cat file2.txt|uniq)
do
    sed -i "/$line.*/s/$line.*/$line.**/" file1.txt
done
```

Expected output:

cat file1.txt

```
MAC* BOOK
MODERN MACHINE*
MECHANICS
MOUNT
DISK
DATA* INFORMATICS
```

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner:

```
$ sed -r '/'"$(paste -sd'|' file2.txt)"'/s/$/*/' file1.txt
MAC*
MACHINE*
MECHANICS
MOUNT
DISK
DATA*
```

The `paste` command creates a regular expression from file2:

```
$ paste -sd'|' file2.txt
MAC|DATA
```

Then the sed command looks file lines matching this regex, and replaces the end-of-line with an asterisk.

Add `-i` to the sed command to complete the task.

---

**Update** for your new input:

```
awk -v patt="$(paste -sd'|' file2.txt)" '{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
       if ($i ~ patt)
           $i = $i "*"
    print
}' file1.txt
```

```
MAC* BOOK
MODERN MACHINE*
MECHANICS
MOUNT
DISK
DATA* INFORMATICS
```

and to edit save the output back into the file:

```
tmp=$(mktemp)
awk ... file1.txt > "$tmp" && mv "$tmp" file1.txt
```

Or, with the latest GNU awk:

```
gawk -i inplace -v patt="$(paste -sd'|' file2.txt)" '{ 
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
       if ($i ~ patt)
           $i = $i "*"
    print
}' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace the "end of line" with * when you match like:

```
for line in $(uniq file2.txt); do
    sed -i "/$line/s/\$/*/" file1.txt
done
```

though this will only work with GNU sed, and it will match `$line` anywhere in the line, so hopefully that's what you expect

Comment: I think you should use the beginning of line match `^`. Without it, this code will also match `*MAC*` and `*DATA*`. Words like `TARMAC` and `VIEWDATA` will match.

Comment: @alvits you could be right, I'm not sure whether matching those things would be desired behavior or not, that's why I included the note that it will match `$line` anywhere in the line

Answer (score 1):

awk is better suited for this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next} {for (i in a) if (index($1, i)) $0 = $0 "*"}1' file2.txt file1.txt
MAC*
MACHINE*
MECHANICS
MOUNT
DISK
DATA*
```

Comment: It will be faster than calling sed N times.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
for line in $(cat file2.txt|uniq)
do
    sed -i "s/\(${line}.*\)/\1\*/" file1.txt
done
```

You can use () in the sed search to save the result and \1 to use it in the replacement.